# Automate addition of missing suffix in single series of `dplyr` pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have multiple dataframes, one of which is shown in abridged form in `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("01 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-6 ", "00:00:01.730 - 00:00:03.040", 
        "02 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-3 ", "00:00:01.740 - 00:00:03.030", 
        "03 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-1 ", "00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.018", 
        "04 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte ", "00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.020", 
        "05 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-2 ", "00:00:01.774 - 00:00:03.023", 
        "06 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-4 ", "00:00:01.778 - 00:00:03.005", 
        "07 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-5 ", "00:00:01.790 - 00:00:02.790", 
        "08 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-7 ", "00:00:01.798 - 00:00:03.025", 
        "09 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-8 ")
  )
```

The values with "Blickkontakt..." all have a numeric suffix but one: the suffix `-9` is missing. I want to **add the missing suffix without hard-coding it** (as there are many dataframes and the suffix may change from one to the other) **and within a single series of pipes** (i.e., only using `dplyr` syntax).

What I've tried so far is a series of individual operations:

```
# define possible range of digits in suffix:
all_suff <- seq(1,9)

# get unique digits from `df`:
library(stringr)
suff <- as.numeric(unique(str_extract(df$V1, "(?<=links_Mitte-|Mitte_rechts-|links_rechts-)\\d")))

# determine missing suffix:
miss <- which(!all_suff %in% suff)

# add missing suffix to `df`:
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(V1 = str_replace(V1, "(?<=links_Mitte|Mitte_rechts|links_rechts)\\s", str_c("-", miss)))
```

How can this process be executed within a single chain of pipes in `dplyr`?

Comment: Is it always only one suffix missing? And is it always clear that there is this one sepcific suffic missing(i.e. there are 8 other rows with suffixes, so we know that the missing row has the missing suffix)?

Answer (score 1):

Stealing most of your code, you could run it in one pipe this way.

```
df |> 
  mutate(suff = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "Blickkontakt"),
                        as.numeric(unique(str_extract(V1, "(?<=links_Mitte-|Mitte_rechts-|links_rechts-)\\d"))),
                        NA_real_),
         miss = setdiff(!!all_suff, unique(suff)),
         V1_new = str_replace(V1, "(?<=links_Mitte|Mitte_rechts|links_rechts)\\s", str_c("-", miss)))

                               V1 suff miss                         V1_new
1  01 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-6     6    9 01 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-6 
2     00:00:01.730 - 00:00:03.040   NA    9    00:00:01.730 - 00:00:03.040
3  02 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-3     3    9 02 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-3 
4     00:00:01.740 - 00:00:03.030   NA    9    00:00:01.740 - 00:00:03.030
5  03 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-1     2    9 03 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-1 
6     00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.018   NA    9    00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.018
7    04 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte     5    9  04 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-9
8     00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.020   NA    9    00:00:01.760 - 00:00:03.020
9  05 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-2     8    9 05 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-2 
10    00:00:01.774 - 00:00:03.023   NA    9    00:00:01.774 - 00:00:03.023
11 06 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-4    NA    9 06 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-4 
12    00:00:01.778 - 00:00:03.005   NA    9    00:00:01.778 - 00:00:03.005
13 07 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-5     1    9 07 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-5 
14    00:00:01.790 - 00:00:02.790   NA    9    00:00:01.790 - 00:00:02.790
15 08 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-7     4    9 08 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-7 
16    00:00:01.798 - 00:00:03.025   NA    9    00:00:01.798 - 00:00:03.025
17 09 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-8     7    9 09 Blickkontakt_links_Mitte-8
```

Of course, you can omit the intermediate vars and replace V1 instead of renaming it. Just showing it here for illustrative purposes.

Comment: And not sure if you'd want to pivot_wider the whole thing to create an additional column for the time stamps instead of having it as additional rows.

Comment: Nice. Just the values in column `suff` are bothering me: there is `5`where the suffix will be added; instead there should be `NA`. To my mind, this works better: `suff = as.numeric(str_extract(V1, "(?<=links_Mitte-|Mitte_rechts-|links_rechts-)\\d"))`

Comment: With the example, it works. But happy to double check if you could provide a regex with some of these edge cases.